# Why rsync --delete flag just puts ~ at end of filename

Tags: rsync

Using the --delete flag in rsync with verbose mode and I see when i run it is says 'deleting file xxxxx'  because the file no longer exists in the source.  However when I list the folder, the file is still there but just with a ~ at the end of the filename?

Comment: Can you please post relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

I'd think those are backup files. From `man rsync`:

> -b, --backup
>                 With this option, preexisting destination files are renamed as each file is transferred or deleted.  You can control where the backup file goes and what (if any) suffix gets appended using the
>                 --backup-dir and --suffix options.
>
> --suffix=SUFFIX
>                 This option allows you to override the default backup suffix used with the --backup (-b) option. The default suffix is a ~ if no --backup-dir was specified, otherwise it is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem before and there's essentially an error in the rsync documentation.  If you are using the -a archive option like I was, which I bet you are, the documentation says -a is equivalent to -rlptgoD  it's actually equivalent to -rlptgoDb  so just use -rlptgoD instead of -a so you aren't using the -b (backup) option inadvertantly